# syslog direct to AWS cloudwatch?

Tags: linux, syslog, amazon-cloudwatch, posix, centralized-logging

Is there a way to push POSIX syslog records directly to AWS cloudwatch? I know Cloudwatch can be rigged to look at the `/var/log/messages` files and similar.

But is there a way -- a sylog.conf(5) setting, or a [rfc5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424) compatible listener, or some such thing -- to send log messages directly?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing ready-to-use I know about but you can try [this](https://superuser.com/questions/607040/are-there-any-command-line-syslog-listeners-for-linux) and modify it to send messages by calling API either with CLI or SDK.

There are AWS docs which may come in handy in sense "how it works": [one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html) [two](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/EC2NewInstanceCWL.html). Also, the docs have links to the code used to grab logs and send events, perhaps it'll be useful for that part of job.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not exactly what your are looking for, but check this out: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/EC2NewInstanceCWL.html